# Full calendar timezone doubts

Tags: timezone, fullcalendar

I have following events array

[image]

My full calendar is initialized like this,

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    timezone: "Asia/Bangkok"
```

However, my calendar shows
[image]

Since my two events are in UTC time, since Bangkok is 7 hours ahead of UTC time, these two events mean start of 8 and start of 10 of Thailand day respectively. Hence my full calendar should render 8 and 10 instead of 7 and 9. I am not sure what specifying the time zone does in this matter. How can I make the events render in my own timezone?

Another thing that is bothering me is the dayClick

```
dayClick: function (date) {
      console.log(date);
```

when I clicked on 14th august, I get the following date

```
Sun Aug 14 2016 07:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
```

since I am in Asia/Bangkok timezone, shouldn't the day click be start of 14th August instead of 7am of 14th August?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [timezone documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/) when you specify a timezone string and events are requested, the timezone name will sent as the [timezone parameter](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/timezoneParam/).

Your server-side script is then expected to use the timezone parameter to calculate the timezone offset of the returned ISO8601 dates!

If you look at the FullCalendar [example](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.9.1/demos/timezones.html) and inspect the returned JSON, you will see that the timezone offset has been calculated server side.

UTC:

[image]

Asia/Bangkok:

[image]